# How do I print the hyperparameters of a fit XGBoost model?

Tags: python, xgboost, hyperparameters

If I fit an XGBoost model on data and set none of the parameters (all are defaults), how do I then print those settings?

`xgb_outofbox = XGBClassifier(random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)`

I'm looking to call something like `xgb_outofbox.params_`, but that doesn't work. I can't find any answers to this very simple question.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** 
`xgb_outofbox.get_params()` with documentation [here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.get_params)

**The Details** 
So say you have a model: "`xgb_outofbox`"

With data:

```
X_train = np.random.random((1000, 10))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)
```

It's a classifier: `XGBClassifier()`

And you provide it the following parameters:

```
params = {"objective": "binary:logistic",
          "max_depth": 7,
          "learning_rate": 0.1,
          "n_estimators": 50}
```

Such that you create the classifier:
`xgb_outofbox = XGBClassifier(**params)`

And then fit the data: `xgb_outofbox.fit(X_train, y_train)`

You would then be able to print out the parameters as follows:
`print(xgb_outofbox.get_params())`

Altogether the code could look like this:

```
import numpy as np
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

# generate data
X_train = np.random.random((1000, 10))
y_train = np.random.randint(2, size=1000)

# hyperparameter dictionary
params = {"objective": "binary:logistic",
          "max_depth": 7,
          "learning_rate": 0.1,
          "n_estimators": 50}

# unpack hyperparameters into classifier
xgb_outofbox = XGBClassifier(**params)

# fit the model
xgb_outofbox.fit(X_train, y_train)

# get the parameters
print(xgb_outofbox.get_params())
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by printing the model object itself, i.e. just write:

```
xgb_outofbox
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That doesn't work. It returns `XGBClassifier()` for me. Nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_xgb_params`:

```
print(xgb_outofbox.get_xgb_params())
```

It returns XGBoost specific parameters.

The output would be something like this:

```
{'objective': 'binary:logistic', 'base_score': None, 'booster': None, 'colsample_bylevel': None, 'colsample_bynode': None, 'colsample_bytree': None, 'gamma': None, 'gpu_id': None, 'interaction_constraints': None, 'learning_rate': None, 'max_delta_step': None, 'max_depth': None, 'min_child_weight': None, 'monotone_constraints': None, 'n_jobs': None, 'num_parallel_tree': None, 'random_state': None, 'reg_alpha': None, 'reg_lambda': None, 'scale_pos_weight': None, 'subsample': None, 'tree_method': None, 'validate_parameters': None, 'verbosity': None}
```